# RSA Javascript encryption and Java Decryption

Tags: java, javascript, security, encryption, cryptography

I've been told to do some own encryption/decryption techniques even though we'll be using https,its just for my learning. It's been like left alone in a jungle in the first day. But managed to gather some enough information. Here's what I'm planning to do.

https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt

Here the encryption and decryption both are done on javascript. But in my case, I've to do encryption in javascript and decryption in Java. As far as I know, we should generate both public and private key in server side, then send the public key to browser, encrypt the submitted data before trasmitting to server.

Then use the private key in server to decrypt the encrypted data. I can't seem to find any exampled for my case (javascript encryption,java decryption), either it comes as pure Javascript or pure Java and not both. Take a look at this.

http://goldenpackagebyanuj.blogspot.in/2013/10/RSA-Encryption-Descryption-algorithm-in-java.html

This is implementation for pure Java RSA encryption decryption. Consider I've been using this code in server side but leave alone the encryption part. Now I've generated both public and private keys. When I go to signin page, I'll get the public key from server by onload function or something else. But I do realise that user data will be vulerable and visible to hackers if my public key fetching fails or encryption fails. So I decided to give warning to users like "Vulnerable connection, please reload" if the any error occurs in encryption part to prevent the plaintext data to be transmetted to the server. Consider now the submitted data is encrypted in client side and received in the server side.

This is my confusing part. Is it possible to decrypt my encrypted data using the java technology which is shown in the last link. coz I doubt there will be differences between javascript encryted data (travist/jsencrypt)  and java encrypted data (blogspot link) or am I wrong coz it's a common encryption standard so that I'll be getting same encrypted data on both techniques?

I'm not asking this on just plain reading, I've tried out this for a day.

https://jcryptionforjava.wordpress.com/

It's quite messing up by combining AES like stuffs. I need it to be simple and got this idea. I know I've not tried the above explanations in realtime, I need to confirm that is this is the way how it works (based on my explanation)? or am I completely wrong about the entire part. Dont want to waste more than a day if I've been completely wrong about my understanding.

Comment: That's basically how this works. I haven't looked at the links, but to ensure interoperability, you have to make sure that matching character encoding, key sizes, padding algorithms, cipher modes and additional data like IV. RSA can be combined with AES which is called hybrid encryption (don't forget padding).

Comment: Furthermore, you cannot ensure that the public key actually reaches the client. An attacker may insert his own public key and play the man-in-the-middle. The attacker can also manipulate the page in such a way that login data is directly sent to the attacker. You have to have some trust in the browser and that is why you need to use TLS/SSL.

Comment: @ArtjomB. thanks for your info, I'm just learning this, not going to implement it in real time servers. Just in local tomcat.

Comment: Also, a good read: http://matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Comment: I read this document before posting my question. Thanks

Comment: watch out for JS's unicode strings vs Java's binary strings.